# Find all $∈ℂ$ such that $|-1|+|+i|=4$

Tags: complex-numbers, conic-sections, absolute-value

I'd like to find all points of the complex plane which satisfy

$|z − 1| + |z + i| = 4 $

I know that $z = x+yi$ and I know this is an ellipsis and that the answer is

$15x^2+15y^2-2xy-16x+16y-48=0$

But I don't know how to get right answer and how to plot a paragraph from the answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is just a geometric set of points: "all the points on a plane the sum of whose distances to two fixed points is a constant is an ellipse.."

Comment: You already know that $z=x+iy$ so $z-1=(x-1)+iy$ and the same goes for the other one. Finally, you need to recall the definition as the absolute value being the distance or length of the complex numbers hence apply Pythagoras and solve using the equality given

Comment: Hint :- $|z| = \sqrt( x^2 + y^2)$ and here $|(x-1)+ \iota y| + |x + \iota(y+1)|$ you can continue from here

Comment: How about seeing complex number as a point of 2-dimensional space(well-known as Cartesian plane), $a+ib$ as $(a, b)$? You would know distance between two point.

Comment: *Hint*: If $z=x+iy$ then your equation is $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}=4$. Move one square root to the other side, square both sides, cancel what you can, you will end up another square root and a few other terms, move everything else to the other side, square again, cancel what you can.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Part $1$: Getting to the Equation**

Assume that $z=x+iy$. We can now substitute this into the equation:

\begin{align}
|z-1|+|z+i|&=4\\
|x+iy-1|+|x+iy+i|&=4\\
|(x-1)+iy|+|x+(y+1)i|&=4\\
\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}&=4\\
\sqrt{x^2-2x+1+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2y+1}&=4\\
\end{align}

We can use a substituation $k=x^2+y^2+1$ (for convenience, use User Deepak's method if you want), and so

\begin{align}
\sqrt{k-2x}+\sqrt{k+2y}&=4\\
\sqrt{k-2x}&=4-\sqrt{k+2y}\\
\left(\sqrt{k-2x}\right)^2&=\left(4-\sqrt{k+2y}\right)^2\\
k-2x&=16+(k+2y)-8\sqrt{k+2y}\\
x^2-2x+1+y^2&=16+(x^2+y^2+2y+1)-8\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2y+1}\\
x^2-2x+1+y^2-16-x^2-y^2-2y-1&=-8\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2y+1}\\
-2x-2y-16&=-8\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2y+1}\\
x+y+8&=4\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2y+1}\\
(x+y+8)^2&=\left(4\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2y+1}\right)^2\\
x^2+xy+8x+xy+y^2+8y+8x+8y+64&=16(x^2+y^2+2y+1)\\
x^2+y^2+2xy+16x+16y+64-16x^2-16y^2-32y-16&=0\\
-15x^2-15y^2+2xy+16x-16y+48&=0\\
15x^2+15y^2-2xy-16x+16y-48&=0
\end{align}

This gives the equation mentioned in your question.

---

**Part $2$: Finding the $x$ and $y$ intercepts of the ellipse**

Now, we can use Desmos for plotting, but by solving the equation for $x=0$ and $y=0$, you can also find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts easily (the method for figuring out the foci has been explained by the User Deepak).

If $y=0$,

\begin{align}
15x^2+15y^2-2xy-16x+16y-48&=0\\
15x^2-16x-48&=0\\
x&=\frac{-(-16)\pm \sqrt{16^2-4\times15\times(-48)}}{2\times15}\\
x&=\frac{16\pm \sqrt{256+2880}}{30}\\
x&=\frac{16\pm \sqrt{3136}}{30}\\
x&=\frac{16\pm 56}{30}\\
x=\frac{-40}{30}=\frac{-4}{3}\ &\text{or } x=\frac{72}{30}=\frac{12}{5}
\end{align}

The $y$-intercepts may be solved in a similar way, by substituting $x=0$ and using the quadratic formula.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I can't see how that can possibly help, in particular because the OP seemed to be unaware of the fact that the equation defines an ellipse...and it doesn't look as such with your work.

Comment: Your fourth line is incorrect, the modulus considers the imaginary part of a complex number which is real. So $|(x-1)+iy|=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+1^2}$.

Comment: I do not doubt it is not helpful, because you made critical miss about norm of complex numbers. That is reason of my downvoting.

Comment: @Dunkelheit I have fixed my answer.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Could you please check if this is right?

Comment: The manipulations you've done need the additional condition $x^2+y^2+2y+1\le 16\land x+y\ge-8$. There's a mistake of sign before the last squaring, which disappears once you've squared. Other than that I don't see issues, but I didn't look too much into it.

Comment: @DonAntonio Could you please check if this is better? If so, could you please retract your downvote? Thank you very much!

Comment: @CheeseCake I almost never downvote, and I didn't in this case, either. By what I see in your post though I can't see anywhere a clear equation of that ellipse (which would probably require of linear algebra to prove it actually is an ellipse), and whose focuses are $\;1,\,-1\;$ in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

I will work through the algebra carefully for your benefit. Some steps seemed natural for me to skip as they were obvious to me. If you can't follow along, I suggest you work through what you find "missing" with pen and paper.

$|z-1| + |z-i| = 4$

$|z-1| = 4 - |z-i|$

Convert to real Cartesian coordinates:

$\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2} = 4 - \sqrt{x^2 + (y+1)^2}$

Square both sides,

$(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 16 + x^2 + (y+1)^2 - 8\sqrt{x^2 + (y+1)^2}$

Don't expand immediately. Exploit the difference of squares identity ($a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$)when rearranging,

$(2x-1) + (2y+1) + 16 = 8\sqrt{x^2 + (y+1)^2}$

$x + y + 8 = 4\sqrt{x^2 + (y+1)^2}$

Square again,

$(x+y)^2  + 16(x+y) + 64 = 16(x^2 + (y+1)^2)$

$x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + 16x + 16y + 64 = 16x^2 + 16y^2 + 32y + 16$

$15x^2 + 15y^2 - 2xy - 16x + 16y - 48 = 0$

exactly as required.

As far as plotting it on axes goes, you can use Desmos or some other computerised solution. Or do it tediously by hand.

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4eslybq0qp) is the plot from Desmos. It is a rotated ellipse, not centred around the origin, about as general as you can get.

But if you were just sketching the curve and wanted the key points, I would focus (no pun intended) on using the original complex locus equation to figure out the foci, which are quite obviously $(1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$. Then note that the axis of symmetry will be the line passing through these points, so $y = x-1$. The centre will be the midpoint of the foci (so that's $(\frac 12, -\frac 12)$). Finally, work out the $x$ and $y$ intercepts and the points of intersection with the axis of symmetry by solving the relevant quadratics, so that's $6$ points in total that define the curve, quite enough to get a good idea of the shape, especially with the symmetry about the axis.

Answer (score -4):

We know that the ellipse is the locus of points whose sum of distances from two fixed points is constant.
If $z$ is any complex number on argand plane then $|z-1|$ denotes the distance of of $z$ from 1 and $|z+i|$ denotes the distance of $z$ from $-i$.

Hence, $|z+i|+|z-1|=4$ denotes the equation of the ellipse where the sum of distances from $-i$ and $1$ is constant. 
We also know that the fixed points are the foci of the ellipse. Hence the foci of the given ellipse are $(1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$.
Therefore, by property of ellipse;
[Solve this equation to get the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZpRa.jpg)
Click on above link for the equation.